# C#, ASP.net application which calls executable to create output file

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are developing a web application in ASP.Net and C#. The requirement here is to interact with a third party exe which is developed in Fortran77. This third party exe produces an output file after being provided with some inputs and shuts down.In windows desktop single user application this is easily possible by using System.Diagnostics.Process and the events provided therein. But in web there will be multi-user environment, and many calls will be made to this exe. What are the best possible ways to handle such an exe in web application?

1. Is it fine if we invoke exe on each user request as the exe shuts down after generating output file? Or
2. Is it possible to use windows service? Or
3. Any other approach?

Thanks in advance.
 -Prasad

Comment: Is the reason you are asking because the output file is overwritten each time? (A concurrent request would conflict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, invoking a different process to do some job (for a request) does not scale well when your number of requests start growing. Said that, if the process invocation is not going to happen frequently then you should be OK. The number of concurrent requests and through-put etc will really depend on your server hardware and the best bet would be to load test the server. As such you should use `Process` class to launch the process to get the work done.

Yet another issue that is possible that your legacy executable does not support multiple instance. It's unlikely but there are quite a few desktop windows application that check for existing instance. So in such, you cannot launch process concurrently and only way would be to create a queuing logic - you can create a in-process queue (in your web application) or create a external application (such as windows service) that will do queuing.

There can be alternate approach for this solution that is useful when the time taken for process to complete is large (so that you cannot block your web requests till the job is complete) and/or you need to scale your app to support more load. Essentially idea is use producer-consumer pattern where your web server will add requests to a persisted (e.g. table in database) queue and then you have multiple machines/servers running a job/windows service that would read from this queue and run the process to generate file.

Comment: • The execution of the Fortran made exe takes less then 5 seconds.
• We can open multiple instance of the exe at the same time which will work separately.
 Please let us know which option will be best suited in this condition to go with either Only Web based approach or Windows service (or even queue sequentially)

Comment: @Prasad, I don't believe that anyone can help you our here. I will suggest that you take the simplest approach to execute the process from web request and then load test your application with intended load. Ideally, you should do the test with production (or similar) server - or at least on the server where interpolating the results to production environment would be simpler. If it pass the load test then you are ok - in future, if you have support more load then you have can add more web servers (scaling out).

Comment: That's True. We have started with the simple approach with only Web application. We will have the load testing as we progress with it. Thanks a lot for sharing your views.